# How do i change the storefront in AppStore to a region thats not even listed in it?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I recently sent an app for review and it got rejected by review board, informing me that , this app is for users from Afghanistan.(TestFlight Beta got accepted though)

```
Hello,

Thank you for your response.

Regarding 3.2, we found that your app is not appropriate for the World storefront because it is a custom app designed specifically for <APP>, whose users are in Afghanistan, China, Dubai, India and South Africa.

Please revise your app to set the storefronts to Afghanistan, China, Dubai, India and South Africa.
```

How the heck am i supposed to add a region which doesnt exist in the storefront page ?(Pricing and Availability -> Availability -> Territories)

Somebody please help me with this.

Comment: What did thy answer when you asked them about it in response?

Comment: I got rejected, i told them that the said country is not available in the list. They sent this back to me again.

Comment: they send you that when you pointed that this territories are unavailable?

Comment: Yes, exactly. They are asking me to do something thats not possible....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talk to apple review team and explain your situation in detail. They might reject you a few times but in the end , they will let you use nearby regions.

Note : Mileage may vary but in the end someone from apple side will help you out !